# Running MongoDB on MAMP Start

Tags: mongodb, mamp, php-mongodb

I am trying to run a shell script which boots MongoDB - but I am trying to run it inside the start.sh script for MAMP PRO so that I do not need to keep booting MongoDB through a Terminal window.

This is not working but just wondering if this is possible or is this an implemented security feature ?

The script (startMongo.sh) is:

```
#! /bin/bash
mongod --dbpath /data/db/ --auth
```

...and I am adding it to the start.sh script like so:

```
# /bin/sh
/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMysql.sh
/Applications/MAMP/bin/startApache.sh
/Applications/MAMP/bin/startMongo.sh
```

Comment: A quick Google search suggests no reasons why MAMP should block MongoDB from starting up. MongoDB just being a deamon program will also not block you from triggering it's startup, infact normally it should come with a premade script. Can you show us the code you put into start.sh?

Comment: Many Thanks, Sorry should have added it - should be able to see it now!

Comment: Hmm two things I see immediately: you start it in auth but provide no keyfile or credentials. Also going by my experience on other UNIX/Linux OS's `data/db/` prolly doesn't match upto anything and you prolly mean: `/data/db/`. Though MAMP might be different there.

Comment: I am running MongoDB at the moment without sharded clusters and replica sets so this runs fine with just the --auth flag. The path to the database works fine if I run it through the command Terminal. Maybe I need to setup MongoDB to run through SSH ?

Comment: You were right though that I needed a slash at the beginning of the db path!

Comment: Ah yea sorry I suddenly thought of the console when thinking that would halt startup :)

Answer (score 0):

Hmm. Looks like I have found my answer and it is not the one I wanted!

http://forum.mamp.info/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=8160&p=17486&hilit=startup+scripts#p17486

Comment: That's gotta be the worst security feature in the history of servers :(